# Firebase Realtime Database, how to know "synchronising" state?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

The server application puts an entry into FRD, and then sends an Firebase Cloud Message. I hear the notification alarm and turns on the Android phone. I see the FCM notification, but I do not see the newly added entry on the app. I wait a few seconds and then it shows up.

I think it may takes a few seconds until the app gets the `onChildAdded`. But how do I know if FRD is synchronising so that I can display something like "Synchronising..." so that users would not wonder why they got a notification for the new entry, but it is not showing up on the app for seconds?

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    ...
    val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    EntriesRef = database.getReference("entries")

    EntriesRef?.addChildEventListener(object:ChildEventListener{
        ...
        override fun onChildAdded(p0: DataSnapshot?, p1: String?)
        {
            //adds the new entry to the Recyler View
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: In which moment are you sending the notification?

Comment: In the service that extends `FirebaseMessagingService`, when the app receives an FCM in `onMessageReceived` and the app is not on the foreground, it creates a notification message.

Comment: Have you tried to use a `DatabaseReference.CompletionListener`? And to send the notification only when the onComplete() is called. This method will be triggered when the operation has either succeeded or failed.

Comment: It is not the app that puts the entry into the FRD; that is done on server. And by the time the app received the FCM, the entry had been already in the FRD. I think it took a few seconds after the start-up of the app until it connects to and gets new data from FRD. Is the event applicable in this case?

Comment: No, is not. I also think that it's about that delay.